# Is it incorrect with Octobercms to work offline then upload the whole work?

Tags: octobercms

I do my work on Octobercms offline and then I upload it.
It was going well until I made my own plugin.
The plugin has a back-end menu for administration.
The site is working well online but the back-end menu refuses to open the plugin admin page.
Instead it throws an exception..
the error is:
[image]
Could anyone, kindly, tell me what this means and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just in case someone faces the same problem, I figured out that the error occurs because my offline platform is windows (file path is case-insensitive) whereas online OS is linux (where file path is case-sensitive). 
So, I just changed 'diaa\quiz\models\**c**ategory' to 'diaa\quiz\models\**C**ategory'